# How Symfony activate automatically the prod mode en MacOS with MAMP

Tags: php, symfony, production-environment

I use the global symfony command to create a project under my `~/tmp/` directory, and aliased it to my `/Application/MAMP/htdoc/` Apache Server's webroot.

Surprise, the project was in prod mode. I know it because the underline debug tool known as the "profiler" is missing and all my bugs was non visible, and when I search in `app/logs/dev.log`, the file is missing too, but there is a `app/logs/prod.log`.

If I run `app/console server:run`, the project is in dev mode.

How is that possible ? Maybe all the software installed by MAMP? 
open_ssl, mod_fastcgi, mod_perl, mod_ssl, mod_wsgi?

I usually only use the build-in server of PHP to run the project and I never set the prod mode before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you to change the value of the second argument of `AppKernel` in `web/app.php`.

Instead I recommend you to configure in your local MAMP setup to use `app_dev.php` as the PHP index file, which is what the `server:run` command does too.

Comment: Aggeed for the argument, quick-and-dirty. But if I change only the `DirectoryIndex` of my vhost (to `app_dev.php`), the `.htaccess` has priority and still uses `app.php`. If I set `AllowOverride` to `None` , my routing is broken and the debug toolbar is not loaded. Can you make it works ?

Comment: I really don't understand because on my Ubuntu VM, with Apache, the `.htaccess` don't manifest like that and I need to select the app_dev.php front_controller, so the url usually looks like : `http://localhost/nameOfTheFolder/web/app_dev.php`

Answer (score 0):

It's due to [the `.htaccess` of the project's `web`directory](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess).

When you browse a Symfony application through Apache, you are in production environment by default, no matter the OS used.

To go in dev mode, open the file `web/app.php` , find the following line :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); // Prod env, debug disabled
```

And change it to :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true); // Dev env, debug enabled
```

It's the quicker way I know.

Otherwise, I made an [override of the default a `.htaccess`](https://gist.github.com/chalasr/52b8dc4f7a5c3f7d77a2) adapted for the dev environment.
It rewrite URLs to the `app_dev.php` front-controller rather than `app.php`.

**Update**

You need to add the following in your apache configuration :

```
<Directory "path/to/your/project">
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

You should create a [vhost](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php) to make this configuration specific to your project, not your whole localhost.

Comment: I don't understand why on my Ubuntu VM the `.htaccess` don't interpret this rule and on MacOS it does

Comment: If you change `AllowOverride all` in your OSX vhost, you'll also be redirected on `app.php`, because the `.htaccess` override the vhost rule. The `.htaccess` I given you as gist in my answer fix the problem for your vm. https://gist.github.com/chalasr/52b8dc4f7a5c3f7d77a2

Comment: I put your `.htaccess` plus set all the `AllowOverride` to `All` and now It don't even work anymore

Comment: No need of change the AllowOverride, keep your configuration as before and replace the content of the web/.htaccess by the content of the gist. It basically rewrite to app_dev.php instead of app.php, I use it in several projects on both osx and ubuntu.

Comment: Done, I'm able to access via `http://localhost/nameOfTheFolder/web/app_dev.php`, so go to the web directory don't bootstrap the front controller app_dev.php with the content of your Gist, the .htaccess is not interpreted... I was thinking that the .htaccess is interpreted only if All is set to AllowOverride

Comment: You need to set the DirectoryIndex to app_dev.php, but it shoud be done either in a named virtual host nor in .htaccess.

Comment: I added changes in my answer.